# How can i get The_author_meta( 'description' ) for all users from all blog_id of wp network

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, author

I try this for get author nickname:

```
    <h2>Articoli di: <span class="nome-autore"><?php global $wpdb, $blog_id;

$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );

foreach ($blogs as $blog){

if(wp_count_posts == 0){
    switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);} else 
    if(wp_count_posts > 0){

    echo $curauth->nickname; }?></span></h2>
```

And then this for meta description:

```
<p>Su di me: <span class="descrizione-autore">"<?php global $wpdb, $blog_id; $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );

foreach ($blogs as $blog){

if(wp_count_posts == 0){
    switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);} else 
    if(wp_count_posts > 0){

    echo  the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>"</span></p>
```

But the problem is that it displays all nicknames and descriptions of each blog_id. How can i select just one value for display?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first gather all the blog ID's then loop over them. This is untested

```
global $wpdb, $blog_id;

$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_blogs ORDER BY blog_id" ) );

foreach ($blogs as $blog){

    switch_to_blog($blog->blog_id);

    $blogusers = get_users('orderby=nicename');

    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->description . '</li>';
    }

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that with this code it shows all meta descriptions together. I need to show each description for just one user id selection.